# The second dual algebra of tensor product

Tags: reference-request, von-neumann-algebras

Let $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ be $C^*$-algebras such that $\mathcal{B}$ is seminuclear (i.e. for every representation $\pi\colon \mathcal{B}\to \mathcal{B}(H)$ the algebra $\pi(\mathcal{B})^{\prime \prime}$ is injective). Do you know some reference for the fact that
$$(\mathcal{A}\otimes _{min} \mathcal{B})^{\ast \ast}= \mathcal{A}^{\ast \ast}\bar \otimes \mathcal{B}^{\ast \ast}$$

as von Neumann algebras? The $\bar \otimes$ denotes the normal spatial product.

Comment: I’m not completely sure if this would work, so I’m writing this as a comment instead of an answer. Given your assumptions, you would have $B^{\ast\ast}$ is injective, so it is the union of an increasing net $E_\lambda$ of finite-dimensional subalgebras. Then you can have an expectation from $A^{\ast\ast} \bar{\otimes} B^{\ast\ast}$ onto $A^{\ast\ast} \otimes E_\lambda$. The latter embeds into $(A \otimes_{min} B)^{\ast\ast}$. So you have a net of ucp maps from $A^{\ast\ast} \bar{\otimes} B^{\ast\ast}$ to $(A \otimes_{min} B)^{\ast\ast}$. Take a pointwise weak$^\ast$ cluster point $F$.

Comment: Then $F$ should give you a left inverse of the natural surjection $(A \otimes_{\min} B)^{\ast\ast} \rightarrow A^{\ast\ast} \bar{\otimes} B^{\ast\ast}$, showing that the latter map is, in fact, an isomorphism.

Comment: Just because I keep seeing it: This is not the definition of a seminuclear $C^\ast$-algebra. A $C^\ast$-algebra $A$ is seminuclear if whenever $\pi(A)^{\prime\prime}$ is semi-finite, then it is nuclear. What you state is equivalent to $A$ being nuclear. I think it is open whether there are seminuclear $C^\ast$-algebras that are not nuclear (or at least it was at the time when Pisier introduced the definition).